FAILED_PRECONDITION: Generation resulted in no candidates matching provided output schema
I created a Cloud Function with Firebase Genkit to generate descriptions of items in images but 90% of the time it throws this error:

FAILED_PRECONDITION: Generation resulted in no candidates matching provided output schema.

My schema looks like this:
const InventoryItem = z.object({
  name: z.string().describe("the name of the item"),
  description: z
    .string()
    .describe("a brief description of the item"),
  funFact: z.string().optional().describe("a fun fact about the item"),
});

My flow looks like this:
export const identifyItemFromUrl = onFlow(
  {
    name: "identifyItemFromUrl",
    inputSchema: z.string().url(),
    outputSchema: InventoryItem,
    authPolicy: noAuth(),
  },
  async (url) => {
    const prompt =
      "Identify this item.";

    const llmResponse = await generate({
      model: gemini15Pro,
      prompt: [
        { text: prompt },
        {
          media: {
            url: url,
            contentType: "image/jpeg",
          },
        },
      ],
      output: { schema: InventoryItem },
    });

    return llmResponse.output()!;
  }
);

How does the generate method work? Does it just randomly create responses until they match the schema? Is there any way to make the output more reliable?

Have looked at the trace in the dev UI? Does it show the actual prompt and llm response?

Yeah as Pavel said the reason is most likely the model failing to return such a result from the input. If you can include the model input/output we can provide a better answer
